# What is the conductor of $K(\sqrt{2})$ over $K$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

Let $ K=\Bbb Q\left(\sqrt{(-1)^\frac{N+1}{2}N}\right)$. I want to find the ray class field of $K$ containing $\sqrt{2}$. I considered $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt{2})$. By Artin reciprocity, there exist modulus $\mathfrak{m}$ such that $L\subset K_{\mathfrak{m}}$, where $K_{\mathfrak{m}}$ is ray class field.
But my problem is to calculate $\mathfrak{m}$.
Any suggestions/comments are very appreciated.

Comment: You discuss $K$, but never define it.  Is $K = \mathbb Q(\sqrt{(-1)^{(N + 1)/2}N})$?

Comment: By the conductor-discriminant formula, $L$ has conductor $8$. The question as it stands is nonsense since there are infinitely many ray class fields containing $\sqrt{2}$.